# Does Println() use memory in live app?

Tags: objective-c, swift

In other words, should a production app eliminate all logging and printing to the console to reduce memory usage (or is the memory usage negligible)?

Answer (score 1):

In general logging take some very small amount of device resources but it is so small that you shouldn't feel any changes unless you are printing a whole book to console ;)

Despite of this, I would recommend to remove all your logs if they are not provide any valuable information to user. Pure debug logs could be very annoying and if someone will work with your code in future, he can call you unprofessional ;)

Comment: Do you recommend removing the println() in code or just disabling the println() function when going live? Ie:  `func println(object: Any) {
    #if DEBUG
        Swift.println(object)
    #endif
}`

Comment: Printlns in code are ok, but you should disable them in your production code. One way to do this is "macro way" you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend removing logs in methods which are called frequently due to the nature of the app (e.g. an update method in a game loop). In such methods one println may cause noticeable stuttering.

You can use a method for logging which will print only in debug (scheme-wise) and do nothing on a release scheme.

Answer (score -1):

You could keep your logs in debug builds, but you better disable them completely, there have been some apps that printed passwords, tokens to the log, which isn't the best thing to do,

Comment: I think we are talking about iOS here, not android ;)